# How can I view events that cause laptop screen to turn on from standby (but not sleep)?

Tags: windows-7, laptop, power-management, event-viewer

On a Windows 7 laptop, is there a way to see exactly **what device or process** triggered the screen to turn on?

I'm referring to the "screen off" mode where the notebook is still on, but the screen has turned off due to inactivity. **Not** sleep mode.

---

Further clarification if needed:

After a set period without user input, Windows power-saving features allow the laptop to progress through various states:

> 1. Fully On → 2. Screen Dim → 3. Screen Off → 4. System Sleep → 5. System Hibernate

I want to be able to detect or see what process or device caused the computer to go from State 3 to State 1 as shown above. For example, if I trigger the screen to shut off (State 1 to State 3) and then the screen turns back on again (State 3 back to State 1), how can I tell what caused it?

Comment: My thoughts are 1) Loose ribbon 2) Power issues (bad cable, adapter, battery). I can't see it though, but from what I read that sounds like a good place to start

Comment: Thanks for your input! The issue is the same whether on AC power or battery, so it would seem to be upstream from the battery or power cable/adapter if it's something wrong with the power hardware. As for loose ribbon... Any ideas loose on what? Anyway I'm still hoping for a way to see what event is causing it so I can find the source of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The best way I know is try to run a command from elevated command prompt `powercfg -requests` and it will let you know what is preventing your system to go into deep sleep.

**Note**: Elevated command prompt means you have to run the command prompt windows as an Admin.

Comment: The computer has no issue with entering sleep...

Comment: Did you tried to run the command? Give a try to it at least once.

Comment: Of course! :D Nothing except an RAS connection running under one of the svchost.exe, which was odd since I thought I had all RAS functions turned off. It's pretty academic at this point though since I accidentally erased Win7 while installing Linux. So... 100% Mint for me now! Thanks though!

Comment: @avirk thank you so much for this command answer, it helped me identify that I had a pending print job that failed that's causing my laptop to not sleep as it should. After clearing the print job, everything started working properly again.